# `git pull --rebase` on feature branch to merge in origin/master changes

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I've read a number of articles and questions regarding `git pull --rebase`, but I'm not sure how it applies to my situation - especially regarding shared/public branches

**Initial Setup:**

- create a feature branch off `master`, push it to the remote
- make changes, commit locally
- push my commits to remote feature branch

**Remote master is updated**

- I want to merge in the `master` changes to my `feature` branch
- `git pull --rebase origin master`

Is the `--rebase` ok to do given that I have already made commits and pushed them?

**Update**
According to Atlassian, once your branch has been pushed (is public) don't use `rebase`

> The golden rule of git rebase is to never use it on public branches.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing#the-golden-rule-of-rebasing

Comment: Are you asking about `git pull --rebase` or do you wonder about `git checkout feature && git rebase master`? `git pull --rebase` is safe, whereas rebasing feature branches might be harmful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the --rebase ok to do given that I have already made commits and pushed them?

**Maybe.**

If other people have checked out your branch (and perhaps even made their own local commits), rebasing has the potential to cause a nightmare of merge conflicts. However, rebasing is often regarded as good housekeeping on projects to keep the history cleaner. When you rebase just before a merge, you are essentially injecting fast-forwardable commits. Without the rebase, you'll merge into your branch first, then push back, which can create messy situations if any individual commit of yours needs to be reverted.

**No Rebase**

```
(main)   A - - - B - - - C - - - D     E
          \                       \   /
(feature)   F - - - G - - - H - - - I
```

**Rebase**

```
(main)   A - - - B - - - C - - - D                   E
                                  \                 /
(feature)                          F - - - G - - - H
```

Comment: The danger only applies for rebasing a branch and force-pushing it to a remote. `git pull --rebase` only works on the local repository, and never the remote. It won't need force-pushes, it doesn't delete public history. Only the local history changes, which nobody knows.

Comment: Yes, but at some point you plan on pushing your changes to remote. When you do that, you will necessarily need to `--force` after a rebase because "I have already made commits and pushed them".

Comment: Again, you don't need to push force for a local rebase with `git pull --rebase`. A push will work just fine as as far as the remote is concerned. You only need to push force when the rebase had to change a remote's history as well, and that happens e.g. when rebasing feature branches with master. Only those need push with force.

Comment: I think you haven't read the scenario. There were prior pushes to the remote for the branch. If then a rebase happens, the next push is necessarily a force.

Comment: @k0pernikus regarding the phrase "doesn't delete public history".  Rebase doesn't even delete local history.  Rebase is non-destructive, and commits are immutable.  A rebase *never* discards any history.  It creates a new commit with a new history, and the branch now references the new commit, but the old history is still there and still intact (unless the garbage collector is tuned very aggressively).

Answer (score 2):

`git pull --rebase` is a safe action as it only works on your local repository. Only your local history will change. You will be able to push afterwards without any `force` / `force-with-lease` flag.

From the remote's perspective, your changes will be the most current ones.

`git pull` would do a merge commit if there are changes on the remote, `git pull --rebase` will rebase your local branch and apply your commits on top keeping the history flat.

---

If you are on a feature branch that exists both locally and on the remote's side, then things might get complicated.

If you do:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/master
```

then you have to also

```
git push --force-with-lease // --force would also work, --force-with-lease prevents accidental deletion of other's commits
```

meaning you change the history of the remote as well. This will lead to problems if multiple people are working or depending on the feature branch. It is safe if you own the remote branch and nobody touches it.

Comment: In my current workflow the `feature` branch exists *locally* and on the *remote* - but it is only myself that is working on it. I make commits on the local feature branch, and push them to the remote (as a backup). After a day or two or working on it, I want to merge in 'master', so my PR won't have conflicts. From your answer it should be safe to do (unless others are using my feature branch). This sound about right?

Comment: Yes, if you own the branch, feel free to rebase.